# It is recommendable to type the color's name instead of its hex value in CSS?

Tags: css, colors, browser

I always forget what colors I'm dealing with in CSS when I see it hex value. I would like to use the name instead (e.g color: lightgreen). Is it supported by all browsers? (or only the basic 16 colors)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any good reasons for using hex over decimal for RGB colour values in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171422/are-there-any-good-reasons-for-using-hex-over-decimal-for-rgb-colour-values-in-c)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is a different question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll prefer the hex value since it is supported by all browsers and I can specify wide range of colors than the named colors.

Answer (score 18):

CSS uses [17 standard colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-color). These are all safe to use. There are also [system colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#system-colors) whose values is system and browser dependent but might be useful for integrating into system defaults but this is deprecated by [CSS3 Color](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#html4) (for whatever that is worth).

Answer (score 5):

Now every popular browsers support the 17 base colors plus 130 more color name 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#svg-color and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp

So not only you can safely use those 17 base colors name but you can also use the 130 SVG 1.0 color keyword names

Answer (score 0):

All colors in rgb.txt are supported by the big browsers, but some may have slightly different definitions. Use the hex code to be safe.

Comment: @Charlie: They are *now*. They weren't *then*.

Comment: Correct, CSS3 wasn't speced out when this comment was made. However, CSS2 spec from 1998 links to HTML4 spec that has the base 16 colors and their RGB values. CSS1 spec doesnt indicate RGB values though.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed reading on this from wikipedia

**[Web colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)**

Answer (score 0):

Use classes then

```
<style>.lightorange {color: #FE7A15 !important}</style>

<div class="lightorange info"></div>
```

This has the benefit you can refine your colors just by updating your CSS. Be aware though it isn't a great idea to name a class after how it appears, since you may want to change all your orange text to red and you'll end up with the class `.lightorange {color:red}` which is just odd.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add comments to your CSS file so instead of:

```
.my_class {
    color: orange;
}
```

You could write:

```
.my_class {
    color: #ffa500; /* Orange */
}
```

This way you know for sure the colour will be exactly the same in every browser and you see the name as well.