# #FFFFFF or "white" in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a difference between `#FFF` (`#FFFFFF`) and `white` in CSS? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230851/are-there-any-cons-to-using-color-names-in-place-of-color-codes-in-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054520/it-is-recommendable-to-type-the-colors-name-instead-of-its-hex-value-in-css

Answer (score 22):

All are supported in the major browsers. It comes down to whichever unjustifiable, deep-seated prejudice you personally have for/against hexadecimal/the English language.

Comment: Does the CSS Standard really state white is #ffffff or is this your assumptions?

Comment: @stefan I try to always go with what I don't really know and can't really prove before anything else.

Answer (score 13):

They're all guaranteed to be the same.  CSS 3 Color Module (a Proposed Recommendation) [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/PR-css3-color-20101028/#html4) white as #ffffff.

It [later says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/PR-css3-color-20101028/#numerical) that values like #rgb are converted to #rrggbb:

> The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is
>   converted into six-digit form
>   (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not
>   by adding zeros. For example, #fb0
>   expands to #ffbb00.

That means that #fff is equivalent to #ffffff (by doubling).

Comment: +1. "That means that #fff is equivalent to #ffffff (by doubling)." No wonder CSS isnt fully supported.

Comment: @Stefan, you're right that there are some weird back/new corners of CSS.  But what's so tricky about doubling?  I think all the major browsers support it.  It's useful when you don't need the full precision.  E.g. #fb0 seems "about right", so you just write that.  Having it be 0-extended would limit the feature to blue-greens. :)

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference. I would imagine browsers take "white" and translate it to "#FFFFFF" in the background. its just a matter of personal coding style which you will use. I prefer using hash because its easier to read and recognise as a colour

Comment: I think you might be one of the only people in the world who thinks hexadecimal values representing a color are *easier to read* than simple color names. Do you really look at #FFA500 and think "oh, orange!"?

Comment: @Cody I look at #FFA500 and think "Oh thats a colour" :) I don't really care what the colour is unless I want to change it. But unless the word is representing a base colour (white, blue, pink etc) the words are just as confusing as the hex values eg: "DarkOrchid" = #9932CC

Comment: I think some colors are easy to recognize by HEX code, after all; they are combinations between channels and we know the first two digits are REDRED, the next two are GREENGREEN and the two last are BLUEBLUE; if we want the fuchsia color, just take the red and blue colors and our HEX code will be something like #FF00FF.
The HEX is more universal than the named colors... but all browsers recognize them! Yeah, the browser, but some developer tools and languages libraries doesn't do.
So, I recommend to use HEX codes and if you have troubles with HEX, comment your code with the color's name.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there is no real difference.  See [this list of supported color names](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp) by all major browsers.  Of course, some will have a preference to one way or the other but for me as long as you keep it consistent it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this question is very old, but Iam trying to explain with my explanation for the new people.

you can use `#F` instead of `#FF` only if there are two same characters followed by each other. Example:`#00FF00` you can use instead `#0F0`. That means `#F` = `#FF` or `#0` = `#00` etc...