# CSS - RGB or HEX for color

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good reasons for using hex over decimal for RGB colour values in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171422/are-there-any-good-reasons-for-using-hex-over-decimal-for-rgb-colour-values-in-c)

Should one use RGB or HEX for colors in CSS style sheets?

If one is favored more than the other, why?

Is there a difference for future proofing, speed of processing, better compatibility between platforms/browsers etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171422/are-there-any-good-reasons-for-using-hex-over-decimal-for-rgb-colour-values-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054520/it-is-recommendable-to-type-the-colors-name-instead-of-its-hex-value-in-css

Comment: hex is quicker to type, I guess, but rgb has much more possible colour combinations.

Comment: @Ben In what way do you mean that rgb has more possible combinations? Hex and RGB are both refering to a point in the sRGB color space. Hex and RGB are just two different representations of the same thing. [CSS spec on color](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#color-type)

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson oops, hex has more, I did the math, 16^6= 16 777 216, and 255^3= 16 581 375

basically, what I meant, was that there are more possible combos with rgb, (even tho there are more w/ hex), and thus more possible colors

Comment: @Ben The number of possible colors are exactly the same for both hex and rgb - 16 777 216. In your calculation you probably forget the zero. 0-255 gives 256 possible numbers thus 256^3, which is 16 777 216 - exactly the same as for hex.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson my bad, sorry

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe that it is mostly a matter of personal taste whether you should use RGB or HEX. Personally I use HEX, because it feels more convenient - it is easier to scan when reading the code and easier to copy from your preferred image editor. Also for colors like white (#fff), black (#000) it could save you a few bytes (not that it would make much difference though).

In the end it is really just two different representations of the same thing, and from a performance perspective I don't think it matters. At least there are loads of other things you can do to increase performance, that will have a greater impact on performance.

Answer (score 16):

Typically, you can copy a hex value from a graphics editor directly — from a *single* text field. For RGB, you can’t: RGB values are usually represented via *three* separate text fields. So hex values are at least easier for everyday use.

But there was no [way](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Sep/0048.html) for a while to use hex notation for values with *alpha transparency*, so we were forced to use RGB notation via the `rgba()` function.

The [CSS Color Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation) draft spec adds the 8-digit hexadecimal notation `#RRGGBBAA` and `#RGBA`: e. g. `#00ffaa80` is equivalent to `rgba(0, 255, 170, .5)`. The feature is available in [Firefox 49+](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=567283), [Chromium 62+](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76362) and Safari 10+ ([WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150853)), but neither in IE nor in Edge. According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=rrggbbaa), such notation is supported by 75% of browsers, so it probably cannot yet be used in the wild, though can be used in browser add-ons.

Answer (score 4):

HEX is stable for an enterprise service. It's easy to maintain (preprocessor and work people friendly), and many browsers are supported.

But, color-name is not bad if you like. It's fun to choose from the color palette, and many colors are defined already.

And so, it's an appendix. I'm using **HLSA** color pattern in my *private experimental* website now. see also if you have an interest to the new CSS3 draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/ .It's very intuitive if you know the color rule of the nature phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

If its for devices (VGA etc) -> use RGBA values, otherwise HEX HSL and pretty much anything works.