# Are rgba color codes heavier to render?

Tags: css, performance, colors

I am more and more using rgba color codes for text in my stylesheets as it easily sets a lighter or darker variation of the color I need (white 80%, black 40%, etc.).

Is there a downside in using rgba color codes as opposed to hexa codes for text? If I want a text to be grey, is rgba(0,0,0,.5) heavier to render than #898989?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6797306/3217006](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6797306/3217006)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate, that question and its answers don't mention rgba once.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a personal option. To me, using hexa codes is easier. It's the same thing at the end of it all. I think it really doesn't matter which one you choose, and won't make any noticeable difference concerning the performance. So, use what makes you more productive! :)