# Which CSS color format is rendering faster?

Tags: html, css

I'm assuming that a browser, internally, has a method to create it's default color format from user css file input, that it can interpret. If I write the following css rules, I think they will point to the same format.

```
<style>
.style {
    color: red;
}
.style {
    color: #f00;
}
.style {
    color: #F00;
}
.style {
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
</style>
```

will result in

```
<style>
.style {
    color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
```

The question might be a little off, but shouldn't the browser render a webpage faster if the color style is it's default format?

Comment: Just a Reference.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797306/performance-differences-between-color-declarations

Comment: Also this website has very cool comparison charts against each browser..http://jsperf.com/css-color-names-vs-hex-codes/18

Comment: @planet260: thanks for the link. it seems it's very hard to test the theory.

Comment: Did you try editing the test.. You can run test on different browsers to see if there is any difference... I just ran it for my Browser Chrome.. You can see the results here.. http://jsperf.com/css-color-names-vs-hex-codes/20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance differences between color declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797306/performance-differences-between-color-declarations)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the results including color names, short hex, hex, rgb, rgba, hsl, and hsla.  You can run the test yourself [here](http://jsperf.com/css-color-names-vs-hex-codes/25).

[image: Color Performance Test Results]