# Does adding many colors in css leads to any performance issue?

Tags: css, colors, performance-testing, background-color

There are some css files, which having around 200 colors and 200 background colors. Does removing colors, which are visually too similar, will give any performance improvement from browser end?

Comment: My gut feeling says no, but I haven't really done any experiments.

Answer (score 0):

No , Removing colors will not improve your page performance. The number of colors you used in your `CSS` is perfectly normal. Using colors in website is very important , so if you compare the need of colors and performance difference(if any) after removing/reducing them is not worth.

If you want to know more about the CSS colors execution [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797306/performance-differences-between-color-declarations)