# should I set a color to a value fromRgb or fromHex xamarin

Tags: performance, xamarin, colors, integer, hex

what I mean to ask is, when setting a color, what are the best practices? getting the integer values first, and setting to Color.FromRgb(int, int, int) or is it the same setting it directly to Color.FromHex(string) (in terms of performance, or course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620719/efficiency-of-color-selection-in-html-rgb-vs-hex-vs-name)

You could try and do a test with a timer to see which is faster as explained in the post linked above "here".